# How to use checkbox to insert or update value in database while inside the WHILE loop

Tags: php, checkbox

I have this Filipino Dishes on my database. But I can't put any data on the show.

```
  img                   name               price       show
curry.jpg     |     Chicken Curry     |     40     |    
karekare.jpg  |     Pork Kare Kare    |     60     |
nilaga.jpg    |     Nilagang Baboy    |     65     |
ptapa.jpg     |     Pork Tapa         |     40     |
sisig.jpg     |     Sisig             |     40     |
```

I want to insert data on the shown column using checkbox. Below is my code.

```
<?php
    echo '<form method="post" action="products.php">';
    include('../store/connect.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM internet_shop");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
    echo '<tr class="record">';
    echo '<td>'.'<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="Items[]">'.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><div align="left">'.'₱'.$row['price'].'</div></td>';
    echo '<td><a rel="facebox" href="editproductimage.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src="../store/img/products/'.$row['img'].'" width="80" height="50"></a></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center"><a rel="facebox" href="editproductetails.php?id='.$row['id'].'">edit</a> | <a href="#" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">delete</a></div></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">';
    echo '</form>';
?> 

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['Items'])) {
        foreach($_POST['Items'] as $value){
        $sql = "UPDATE internet_shop SET show = $value";
        }
        }

}
    ?>
```

But I can't seem to insert data to the show column using this code. I want to do this so that I will  only just check the items that is checked using the `("SELECT * FROM internet_shop WHERE show='yes'")` query.

Comment: What is the error(message)?

Comment: When I click the submit button nothing happens. It doesn's show anything.

Comment: Will that also work even when the checkbox is inside the while loop?

Comment: You have to launch the, query, You only set the query. Add something like this _$result = mysql_query($sql);_ . P.S mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: @Sfili_81 in what part should I add that?

Comment: Just after the declaration of $sql